# Multiple ffmpeg in parallel, same input

Tags: multithreading, ffmpeg, multiple-instances

I'm running multiple instances of ffmpeg in parallel, to see if the cpu can handle them. I'm running something very simple like taking in input 60 seconds of an rtsp stream and copying it into a mp4 file.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.28.0.52/axis-media/media.amp -c copy -r 15 -t 60 \ 
"video02.mp4" < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I want to run 40 of these exact instances in parallel, but some just do not run. For example if I run that command 10 times, at least 2 or 3 just do not do anything, or are dropped instantly. Is it ffmpeg that limits multiple operation on the same input?
If I run 30 instances, it still drops four or five of those. What is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does ffmpeg say anything interesting if you don't redirect the stdout and stderr to /dev/null?

Comment: it complains about buffer size

[udp @ 0x14db9a0] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[udp @ 0x14daa20] end receive buffer size reported is 131072